# Finding RGB image contrast

Tags: image, image-processing, rgb, contrast

I want to preprocess images before comparing them. Hence I am making their brightness and contrast same and gray scaling them before comparison. For computing brightness I have used the formula

```
((Red value X 299) + (Green value X 587) + (Blue value X 114)) / 1000
```

Is there any formula by which you can get the contrast value or contrast ratio in an image so that I can set both the images to same contrast before comparing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard methods to match the contrast levels of two or more images are [Histogram Equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) and [Histogram Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching).

Comment: Good suggestion although I would also recommend looking at [Histogram matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching) as well. Instead of equalizing both images, just match one to the other.

Comment: Thanks - I thought this was in a sub section of that wiki page. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Histogram however isn't there any way that I an get the contrast value in an image like the HSB value that I can get of pixels